# Redefine \section to take one more input

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I want to redefine `\section` command so that it can take one input, `\sectiondesc`; which would contain a description about it. Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%%% old definition
\section[short title]{Long Title}

%%% new definition
%\section[short title]{Long Title}{Really long description \\ multiple lines, often with graphics \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
    \begin{center}
        \normalfont
            % \sectiondesc
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way with `xparse` and `\RenewDocumentCommand` is the easiest one, in my point of view.

I suggest to use `\section[]{}[]` however, i.e. its possible to omit the section description.

The `\sectiondesc` macro is redefined to be expand to nothing with every `\section` call, so omitting the 4th argument will provide no section description.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\beameroldsection\section% Store the old definition first

\def\sectiondesc{}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m+O{}}{%
  \gdef\sectiondesc{}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% Grab the starred version, i.e. \section*
    \beameroldsection*{#3}%
  }{%
    \beameroldsection[#2]{#3}%
    \gdef\sectiondesc{#4}% Store argument 4
  }%
}


\begin{document}


\section[short title]{Long Title}[Really long description \\ multiple lines, often with graphics \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}]

\begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
    \begin{center}
        \normalfont
             \sectiondesc
    \end{center}
\end{frame}


\section*{Foo}
\begin{frame}
  \sectionpage
    \begin{center}
        \normalfont
        \sectiondesc
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow-up question [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380242/properly-use-atbeginsection-beamer] :-)