# Properly use AtBeginSection Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I have this MWE (follow-up from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380236/38244))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\beameroldsection\section% Store the old definition first

\def\sectiondesc{}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m O{}}{%
    \gdef\sectiondesc{}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% Grab the starred version, i.e. \section*
        \beameroldsection*{#3}%
    }{%
        \beameroldsection[#2]{#3}%
        \gdef\sectiondesc{#4}% Store argument 4
    }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}{\insertsection}\par \insertsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}

    \begin{center}
        \sectiondesc        
    \end{center}

}


\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}{Overview}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
            nothing?\sectionpage%\sectiondesc %%% Tried both `\sectionpage` and `\sectiondesc`
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}


    \section[short title]{Long Title}[Really long description \\ multiple lines, often with graphics \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}]

    \begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
    \end{frame}


%   \section*{Foo}
%   \begin{frame}
%   \sectionpage
%   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I tried to do is to have the `\sectionpage` at the beginning of every section. However, the `\sectiondesc` is empty at this page.

What should I do to print `\sectiondesc` in the beginiing slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\AtBeginSection` code is 'executed', before the rest of `\section` is called, i.e. the real section code (`\beameroldsection`). In the definition of the answer in the linked question the `\sectiondesc` is `\gdef`ed to be `{}`, so this is empty in the beginning always.

`\gdef\sectiondesc{#4}` works, if there is no description (i.e. the 4th argument is empty) the `\sectiondesc` macro expands to nothing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\beameroldsection\section% Store the old definition first

\def\sectiondesc{}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m O{}}{%
  \gdef\sectiondesc{#4}% Store the 4th argument beforehand
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% Grab the starred version, i.e. \section*
        \beameroldsection*{#3}%
    }{%
        \beameroldsection[#2]{#3}%
     }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}{\insertsection}\par \insertsectionhead
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}

    \begin{center}
      \sectiondesc
    \end{center}

}


\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}{Overview}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
            \sectionpage%%% Tried both `\sectionpage` and `\sectiondesc`
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}


\section[short title]{Long Title}[Really long description \\ multiple lines, often with graphics \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}]

\begin{frame}
  \sectionpage
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]